# Unable to see Chrome menu buttons

Tags: google-chrome

How do I change the color of the menu buttons on Chrome?

As you can see from the image provided the refresh button is hardly visible. How can I change the color so I can more easily see the refresh and other button on Chrome?  [image]

Comment: What's your operating system? What themes are you using for it and for Chrome?

Answer (score -1):

You can try changing your Chrome theme or using the default theme.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Explaining HOW to change the theme will make this a better answer.